# Need to restore from encrypted iPhone backup, but can’t due to missing password

Tags: iphone, ios, restore, data-recovery

I did **not** set a password for the restore encrypted thing. I have tried *1234* and anything else I could come up with. I *have* to get back in. I accidentally deleted text messages that I need for personal reasons. I called Apple, and they basically admitted that this could happen somehow, but they had no remedy. Is this true?

Comment: The odds of the software getting corrupt and looking like your backup was encrypted is a very long odds / low chance event, but with millions and millions of phones, even odd corruption will be seen. Also, they don't want to insult you when the likely answer is *someone* clicked the "encrypt my backup" form and typed a password, twice.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would try your iTunes password and any others you can think of.  Passwords don't magically set themselves.  You or someone else must have enabled the Encrypt iTunes Backups feature, which requires setting a password.
2. You might be in luck, because deleting text messages (at least in iOS 4.x) doesn't actually erase the data, it still exists in your sms.db file hidden on the phone.  You could seek an experienced iPhone expert to help you jailbreak and access your sms.db, or use a tool like DiskAid or PhoneView to attempt to access the Messages sms.db directly.  Then you (they) would use an SQLite database browser to search and view the text messages.

Comment: Thank you please keep the comments coming.  The elcomsoft has been working for 14 hours at 710 password a second and says it has 955 days left......on a code level of 6 chrachters including letters and numbers. But i am affraid to disconnect the phone frome computer and my computer is running plugged in constantly. Called apple corporate today, they got off the phone as fast as they could. but still I need to get this cracked so please keep any and all help coming Thank you for all replies.dont know anyobw that high tech, but i will try to find someone incase i have to try that route as well.

Comment: There is forensic software that reads the keys from your PC and works to unlock devices and backups even without knowing the pass phrase. The last time I checked, the software ran in the $1200 to $900 dollar range and includes several hours of training on how to use it. Anything is crackable with enough money and or training, but iOS backup encryption is fairly challenging for even smart engineers to crack.